# FetchLinkID-Information from TopologieID

Tags: here-api

I'am using the matchroute.json API to MapMatch my GPS Trace on the Links. Now I want to fetch the TopologyID of the driven link. This is possible with &attribute=STAB_TOPO_ID_FCN(TOPOLOGY_ID). But I also want the information about which LinkIDs are on this TopologyIDs. I saw there is an Option in TOPO_SEG_LINK_FCN(LINK_IDS), but it seems that it doesn't work like espected.

Is there an Option to get the LinkIDs Information for a specific TopologyID?

Example what I tried: https://rme.api.here.com/2/matchroute.json?app_id=XXX&app_code=XXX&legal=access,gate,oneway,thrutraf,turn&attributes=TOPO_SEG_LINK_FCN(TOPOLOGY_ID),LINK_ATTRIBUTE_FCN(TRAVEL_DIRECTION),LINK_FCN(REF_NODE_NEIGHBOR_LINKS,NONREF_NODE_NEIGHBOR_LINKS),STAB_TOPO_ID_FCN(TOPOLOGY_ID,LINK_IDS)&routemode=car&file=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%3D%3D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The route matching API provides information that matches the links along your route. So for each matched link, the TAB_TOPO_ID_FCN layers gives the topology ID. However, to get all link IDs in a topology ID, you will need to separately retrieve this information from the TOPO_SEG_LINK_FC{N} of the Fleet Telematics Advanced Data Sets.
https://developer.here.com/documentation/platform-data/topics/what-is.html